# MongoDB(Java) insert's document that is already inserted

Tags: java, mongodb

I got a problem with my java code. I check if the user already exists before creating it. But that does not seem to work. I logged in to the mongo shell and checked if the document has been created. The document has been added succesfully.

Here is my class. The method that is not working is createMyTrazUser():

```
public class MyTrazUser {


String name;
Player player;
List<World> worldList = new ArrayList<World>();

public MyTrazUser(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.player = Bukkit.getPlayer(name);
}

public boolean hasPlot() {
    //Not finished
    return new File("/BuildEvent/" + getUUID() + ".yml").exists();
}

public UUID getUUID() {
    //We can do this request because the Fetcher class caches the uuid's for us.
    return UUIDFetcher.getUUID(this.name);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Player getPlayer() {
    return player;
}

public ArrayList<String> getWorlds() {

    DBCursor playerFind = Bootstrap.getMongoManager().getPlayers().find(new BasicDBObject("UUID",getUUID()));
   DBObject found = playerFind.next();
   if(found == null) {
       System.out.println("Backend -> User not found! We do not create the user because there could be an error!");

   } else {
       return (ArrayList)found.get("Worlds");
   }
  return null;
}

public void createMyTrazUser() {

    String uuid = getUUID().toString();

    DBObject request = new BasicDBObject("UUID",getUUID());
    DBCursor cursor = Bootstrap.getMongoManager().getPlayers().find(request);

    if(!cursor.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("Cursor next: " + cursor.next());
        List<String> playerWorlds = new ArrayList<String>(); //Player can't have any worlds at the creation so we will leave that null
        //Building up the Document
        DBObject playerRequest = new BasicDBObject("UUID",uuid)
                .append("Name", UUIDFetcher.getName(UUID.fromString(uuid)))
                .append("RegisterTimestamp",new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date()))
                .append("Worlds",playerWorlds)
                .append("Logins",1);
        //And  flush!!!!
        Bootstrap.getMongoManager().getPlayers().insert(playerRequest);
        //We print the just created user to see if something went wrong.
        System.out.println("Backend -> Created user with the following entries: " +
                playerRequest.toString());

    } else {
        System.out.println("Backend -> User already exists. OK.");
        return;
    }

}

public DBObject getDocument() {
    DBCursor playerFind = Bootstrap.getMongoManager().getPlayers().find(new BasicDBObject("UUID",getUUID()));
    if(playerFind == null) {
        if(playerFind.hasNext()) {
            DBObject found = playerFind.next();
            if(found == null) {
                System.out.println("Backend -> User not found! We do not create the user because there could be an error!");
                return null;
            } else {
                return found;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Backend -> Could not get request user info! Report!");
        return null;
    }
    System.out.println("Backend -> Could not get request user info! Report!");
    return null;
}
```

}

new MyTrazUser(player.getName()).createMyTrazUser();

I hope you can help me with my code

Best regards

Comment: You showed the createMyTrazPlayer() method, but you don't show us how you call it.  Show the code where you call it.

Comment: I call the method in line 36.

Comment: Not seeing it.  Are you referring to the "pubic void createMyTrazUser()?

Comment: I now added the line to my question.